# Using Cygwin to run nginx on Windows

Tags: cygwin, nginx

Is it possible to run a Linux installation of nginx from Cygwin? Or should I run the Windows version? Basically I want to be able to restart Cygwin from command prompt instead of having to end the process in the task manager when I change the config file. Windows nginx doesn't support this but Linux nginx does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is restart something from the command line in Windows, you can terminate a running process via command line with the `taskkill` command, or the `stop-process` cmdlet in Powershell.

I don't see nginx in [list of Cygwin packages](http://cygwin.com/packages/) so you'd have to download the nginx sources and compile under cygwin for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [chocolatey package manager](https://chocolatey.org/) with `nginx-service` for running `nginx` on Windows.
It uses [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) to manage `nginx` as a service.

Then, it's as simple as opening `cmd` and 'nssm restart nginx-service' to restart `nginx`.
Installation is by loading chocolatey, restarting your terminal and doing

```
choco install nginx-service
```

**Note:**
I am fully aware that this is running the natively compiled for Windows `nginx`, not a version compiled against Cygwin. However, it performs all the tasks needed very well.

Answer (score -1):

Updating this because this is the first entry for "cygwin start nginx" when searching with google.

- It is not "a Linux installation of nginx from Cygwin". It is a version of nginx compiled against the libraries that are compiled against the cygwin DLLs. See: https://cygwin.com/index.html
- Since Cygwin provides a version, it better be possible.
- The nginx binary is in /usr/sbin. That doesn't show up in your path unless you add it.
- According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html you can do this at the windows console, just like the Cygwin console:

```
    nginx -s stop   fast shutdown
    nginx -s quit   graceful shutdown
    nginx -s reload changing configuration, starting new worker processes with a new configuration, graceful shutdown of old worker processes
    nginx -s reopen re-opening log files
```

(OK, so "code blocK doesn't behave the way I'd expect. Had to tag it manually)

- Accordingly the answer to *MY* question (dropped here so that others might benefit):

/usr/sbin/nginx.exe

Comment: This sounds like *your* question is slightly different, this means the community would be better served by you submitting your own question, then answering it yourself.

Comment: Google sent me here, and my question was REALLY dumb. 
As in brain fart dumb. 

I don't know what it takes to change Google's mind. Because Google.

Comment: Be sure your answer, addresses the author's question, and isn't an answer to your question (which while similar isn't actually the author's question).

Comment: @Ramhound I do not think the OP was asking 'how do I get a Linux compiled version of nginx on Windows/cygwin' as it appears to be phrased, but rather 'how can I get linux command line functionality on nginx on Windows.' - Eventhough the Q is a bit badly worded. If the latter Q is true than I would say that Petro's answeer does answer it.  Also, a lot of cygwin users do not understand that it is not a linux-compile so it is handy to point this out.

Comment: @BenjaminGoodacre - The author of this answer literally indicated they answered their own question instead of the author’s question

Comment: I'm really starting to hate the kind of people that make Stack Exchange a lifestyle.